# How can I check if a letter was already read

Tags: c, user-input

Can anyone help me how can my program read if a letter is input again so it can prompt "letter was already read"?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char alphabet[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char letter;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
    printf("%s\n\n", alphabet);
    printf("Choose a letter: ");
    letter = getchar();

    printf("\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (letter == alphabet[i]) 
         {
            alphabet[i] = '_';
            break;   /* This terminates the for() loop */
         }        


    }
     printf("Result: %s\n", alphabet);

     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's fairly easy. You may have another array with size 26 and initiate with all false, whenever you get a character, you set the corresponding slot to true. Then when you get a character and want to check whether it was inputted already, you just check whether the corresponding slot is true or false.

BTW, I don't think you want the inner for loop to use i also. You may want to use another variable, say, j, because the outer for loop is using i as controller, which may cause problems.

Comment: @user2803376 I don't want to give the code. This is not a place where you can always get an answer easily. I believe the thinking process is more evaluable to you.

Answer (score 0):

If your input consists only of capital letters, then the letter was already provided if and only if you reach the end of your inner loop, *i.e.* if the letter is not found in the alphabet because it has already been replaced by `_`. One way to check for this is to check if `i` equals 26 after your inner loop. A slightly cleaner way would be to use a boolean to indicate if you did break out of the inner loop.

Now if your input can be any character, it would be best to use a separate array to keep track of the letters already provided instead of replacing letters in `alphabet`. You could have:

```
const char alphabet[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int count[26] = {0};
```

and

```
if (letter == alphabet[i]) 
{
    ++count[i];
    break;
}
```

to keep track of exactly how many times each letter was provided.

Comment: how can i print that the letter is already entered after that?

Comment: Before incrementing the count, you could test if the count is greater than zero. If it is, then the letter was already provided.

Comment: I won't do it for you. I gave you many hints. Try things, go as far as you can and if you are still stuck, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have an array of inputted letters, if not you can use two Variables

```
char prevletter;
char latestletter;
```

in this you can compare if the prevletter is equal to latest letter

```
latestletter = getchar();

if (prevletter == latestletter)
{
printf("Alredy inputted this");
}

else 
{
prevletter =latestletter;
}
```

this code only works for consecutive letters if you want to know if a letter has been inputted not consecutively but repeated after other tries you can use an array

```
     char inputletters[xx];

use for loop to check if it exist in the array if yes `printf the warning else continue`

  char inputletters[xx];

  for(i = 0; i < xx; i++)
    {
        if (letter == inputletters[i]) 
         {
           printf("AlreadyInputed");

           Break;
         }        


    }
```

then do your process here in inserting the inputed letter if it does not exist in the array of inputed letters

Comment: Sir hindi ko po magets.

Comment: ganto.. gumawa ka nang array isa pa dun mo ilalagay ung mga iniinput mo na letters, tapos kada input mo gayahin mo ung code ko sa taas. sa loob ng for loop iccheck nya kung me kaparehas ung next input mo dun sa mga nasa laman ng aarray mo. pag wala ipasok mo sya sa loob tapos gawin mo ung process kung merun nman iprintf mo already inputted un :)

Comment: ah so dapat `char alphabet[27]: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` at `char inputletter[27]` at  `char letter` ang laman ng code ko ganun po ba?

Comment: haha pwede makipagfriends sayo tol, grabe marami pa akong di alam sa programming kaya matanong ako eh, pati minsan talaga nahihirapan ako. hehe, sorry for not speaking in english dude :)

Comment: @user2803376 Yup You're Right,every after input check in the inputletter if the Current inputted letter is already there if yes, prompt the user, if no include the current letter in the array, perform the other processes you need to do.

Comment: @user2803376 yup, sure why not im welcome to friendship always :)

Comment: @user2803376 bale dalawa for loop mo isa sa checking kung nainput na ba ung letter dati ung isa para dun sa pinag lalalagay mo sa taas. hahahaha

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand your code and it looks to me as php is mixed with javascript. Anyway,.... if it was up to me, I would take a different approach and, supposing we are talking php here, although you could do the same in javascript, create an array first. Each time a letter is inputted, I would check if the letter is in the array. If it is, you can have an alert pop up saying the letter has been inputted, and if not, "push" that letter in the array.

Something like this...

```
<?php  
$a = array();  
$input is "a";  
if (in_array($input, $a)) // if the letter "a" ($input) is in the array...  
    {  
    echo "This letter was already entered.";  
    }
else // if it's not in the array  
    {  
    array_push($a, $input); // add the letter ($input) to the array  
    }
?>
```

If you want to make this case insensitive, you can convert all input to lower case (or upper case)

```
$input = strtolower("a");
```